# Is inertia the same as centrifugal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, centrifugal-force, inertia

My cousin told me that inertia is just a pseudo force that act on a thing, because he said that inertia is the same as centrifugal force. But when I search for the true fact in Google, I found that inertia is real ? I'm confused, please clarify the true fact.

Answer (score 2):

[Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia) is a generalisation of the concept of mass, referring to the tendency to resist changes in motion. Your cousin may be thinking of [inertial forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_force), which is just another term for pseudo-forces (like the centrifugal force).

Answer (score 1):

Inertia really just means the absence of action (from its Latin meaning, the language used by Newton). It is often identified with mass, sometimes called inertial mass, which can be seen as a resistance to change in motion caused by an active force. For myself, I don't like using a word which means the absence of something to mean something real.

An inertial object is one which is not acted on by an active force.

Inertial forces (including the centrifugal forces) describe accelerations caused by the choice of reference frame, and which are not caused by an active force.

Answer (score 0):

Inertia is an effect that is observed in all frames.  It is the tendency for an object at rest to remain at rest until acted upon, and is captured with the concept of "mass."

Centrifugal force is a pseudoforce which appears in the equations of motion in a non-inertial rotating frame.  They are different.

However, in most situations where we would want to use a rotating frame of reference, there is something which opposes outward motion and makes the rotating frame useful (the equations of motion in a rotating frame are always valid, but they're not convenient unless there's something in the problem like a "floor" that's rotating).  In these situations, you have two different viewpoints.  In the rotating frame, there's a centrifugal acceleration (or a centrifugal pseudoforce), opposed by a centripetal force.  In an inertial frame, that same behavior is captured simply in the inertia of the objects involved.  Its the desire for the object to keep moving in a straight line while some other object forces it into a curved path.

In the strictest sense they are different.  There's times you can get away with treating them as if they were the same, but every now and then it will cause confusion.  Treating them different will yield the correct answer in all cases.

Comment: _tendency for an object at rest to remain at rest_ is Aristotle's physics, not Newtonian. Newton's inertia explicitly includes uniform rectilinear motion as the state of an un-acted-upon object.

Answer (score 0):

- [Inertia](https://www.allthatmatters.academy/courses/forces/lessons/inertia-mass/) is the "toughness" that (almost) everything has when you try to catch or throw it (slow it down or speed it up). It is a natural, **inert resistance against acceleration/deceleration**.
- [The centrifugal effect](https://www.allthatmatters.academy/courses/motion-2/lessons/centrifugal-effect/), the feeling of being flung outwards when sitting in a turning car, or flung into the seat of a roller-coaster at the top of its loop, is a phenomenon that happens *due* to the fact that stuff has inertia.

Many phenomena happen due to the fact that stuff has inertia. One of those phenomena is the centrifugal effect, which is a term only used for the feeling of being flung outwards when in circular motion.